# loading .Random.seed producing inconsistent results in RStudio background job

Tags: r, random, rstudio, random-seed

I'm working on a function that wraps around `rstudioapi::jobRunScript()` to submit code to RStudio background jobs. I want the code run by the background job to produce the exact same results as if run in the normal parent session, including when random number generation is used. I'm trying to do that by saving and loading the `.Random.seed` object.

The documentation for `?set.seed`/`?random` states that the hidden `.Random.seed` object

> can be saved and restored, but should not be altered by the user.

In normal R/RStudio sessions, behavior after running `set.seed()` does seem to be reproducible between sessions by saving and loading the `.Random.seed` object.

```
set.seed(1)
rnorm(1)
#> [1] -0.6264538
set.seed(1)
saveRDS(.Random.seed, "seedfile.RDS")
```

After restarting R, or in a separate session, or in the same session:

```
.Random.seed <- readRDS("seedfile.RDS")
print(rnorm(1))
#> [1] -0.6264538
```

Behavior here, as expected, is the same and replicable across sessions. However, if I submit the same code to an RStudio background job, such as by running the following:

```
writeLines("
.Random.seed <- readRDS('seedfile.RDS')
print(rnorm(1))", 
"script")
rstudioapi::jobRunScript("script")
```

I get results that are neither consistent with the above nor consistent between trials, e.g.:

[image: -0.8859877 printed from Background Jobs]

I can get consistent reproduction if I include `set.seed(1)` at the beginning of the job code. However, for a number of reasons, I would much prefer to achieve reproducible behavior by saving and loading the `.Random.seed` file instead. I also cannot rely on the `importEnv = TRUE` argument for `rstudioapi::jobRunScript()`; I need to perform the loading within the job using my own code.

Why do RStudio background jobs give inconsistent results even with the same .Random.seed file, and why does this not occur when simply starting a new normal R session? Is there a way I can resolve this without needing to call `set.seed` within the job?

Answer (score 0):

"I would much prefer to achieve reproducible behavior by saving and loading the .Random.seed file instead." this wont work.

You should not share/ pass mutable objects between different environments!
Explanation: because the `.Random.seed` object keeps track of its current index, when you call `saveRDS` it also saves that index.  When you reload it from a file using `readRDS`, it starts at the index it was saved at.  As you can see in the example:

```
setwd("~/Documents/rtest/")
## Remove all objects from current env:
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
ls(all.names = TRUE)
# empty

## initialize random seed object at index 1
set.seed(1)
ls(all.names = TRUE)
# [1] ".Random.seed" appears !

# use first three pseudo random number indices:
for (i in 1:3) {
  print( runif(1) )
}
# [1] 0.2655087
# [1] 0.3721239
# [1] 0.5728534

# save seed state
saveRDS(.Random.seed,"seedfile.RDS")

## now mark this code
## and use " Code : Run selection as Background Job"
## and use " Run job with copy of global environment ☑"

for (i in 1:3) {
  print( runif(1) )
}
# reload seed state from file 
.Random.seed <- readRDS("seedfile.RDS")
# next three pseudo random indicies are used:
for (i in 1:3) {
  print( runif(1) )
}
# [1] 0.9082078
# [1] 0.2016819
# [1] 0.8983897

# reload seed state from file again
.Random.seed <- readRDS("seedfile.RDS")

for (i in 1:3) {
  print( runif(1) )
}
## same three pseudo random indicies are used:
# [1] 0.9082078
# [1] 0.2016819
# [1] 0.8983897

# if run again - 
for (i in 1:3) {
  print( runif(1) )
}
# - next three pseudo random indicies are used:
# [1] 0.9446753
# [1] 0.6607978
# [1] 0.629114

# save seed state to file
saveRDS(.Random.seed,"seedfile.RDS")

# re-set enviornment seed:
set.seed(1)
# first nine pseudo random numbers 
for (i in 1:9) {
  print( runif(1) )
}
# we have already all seen them!
# [1] 0.2655087
# [1] 0.3721239
# [1] 0.5728534
# [1] 0.9082078
# [1] 0.2016819
# [1] 0.8983897
# [1] 0.9446753
# [1] 0.6607978
# [1] 0.629114
## the next three
for (i in 1:3) {
  print( runif(1) )
}
# we havent seen those yet
# [1] 0.06178627
# [1] 0.2059746
# [1] 0.1765568

# lets load the pseudo random number generator
.Random.seed <- readRDS("seedfile.RDS")
# can you guess the next three numbers?
for (i in 1:3) {
  print( runif(1) )
}
# [1] 0.06178627
# [1] 0.2059746
# [1] 0.1765568
## right! the same as the three above.
# et cetera....
.Random.seed <- readRDS("seedfile.RDS")
for (i in 1:3) {
  print( runif(1) )
}
# [1] 0.06178627
# [1] 0.2059746
# [1] 0.1765568
```

If you opt in to Run job with copy of global environment ☑ it should be more reproducible, however i would advise against it and just evaluate `set.seed` at the beginning of each script, this will assure that you have reprpoducible results.

Comment: "because the .Random.seed object keeps track of its current index, when you call saveRDS it also saves that index. When you reload it from a file using readRDS, it starts at the index it was saved at." Right, so it should be reproducible then, and it is inside normal R sessions. But when I call readRDS() inside of a background job, it doesn't replicate. I'm still not clear on what accounts for this difference.

Comment: I have edited the question to make the problem clearer. I can't rely on exporting the whole global environment to the background job.